# Is there any possibility to break while loop " while(Scanner.hasNext())" without condition of break it?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm bothering with such problem for long hours:
Task is " blah blah.. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for.. "
And Like I said int title I'm using this condition "hasNext". How I can break this loop without clear knowledge of ending input, what will be write in console and amout of input? I was thinking that do while loop will help me, but still without expected result :(.

Thanks for any answers and sorry if it's so obvious to answear-I was looking for similar questions/answears, but none of it worked :(

EDIT( and complete task is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();

    for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
        String name = sc.next();
        int numer = sc.nextInt();
        map.put(name, numer);
    }
  while(sc.hasNext()){
       String name=sc.next();
       sc.nextLine();
       list.add(name);
    }
    sc.close();
    for (String k : list) {
        if (map.containsKey(k)) {
            System.out.println(k + "=" + map.get(k));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: Check for two conditions in your while statement and break if one of them isn't true... `while(something.hasNext() && !breakLoop)...`

Comment: But still what that "breakLoop" would be? My input looks like: name1 <enter>, name2<enter> and so one. I cant figure out what that whitespace or sth could be :/

Comment: _"You will then be given an unknown number of names"_. How do you get the names? From a file or from the console, or something else?

Comment: They are from console

Comment: I gess it takes new line as next String. What is more this user is online verify-compilator(I do not have any clue how to name it properly, but what is important it's making several test that differs form each other  ) so I do not know the input and amout of it

Comment: As far as I know, `scanner.hasNext()` returns true while the user supplies a line through the console. So, if you just use a while loop with the aforementioned method, the loop will iterate and it will terminate as soon as the user stops. But, the user must send an EOF character to inform the Scanner class that the input has been closed, which is not easy when the Scanner has been initialized using the Standard Input Stream. So, you either expect that an EOF character will be generated sometime or you have to come up with an escape String, as the others suggested.

Comment: I do not have this guarantee :/ But still it has to be way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = sc.nextInt();
    for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
        String name = sc.next();
        int numer = sc.nextInt();
        map.put(name, numer);
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name;
    while ((name = in.readLine()) != null && name.length() != 0) 
    {
        list.add(name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (map.containsKey(list.get(i))) 
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + "=" + map.get(list.get(i)));
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `break`.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String next = scanner.nextLine();
    if(next.equals("quit")){
        //you will exit the loop here
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(next);
    //more code here

}
```

Comment: Nope It won't help me :/ I do not know of words that will be use in input :/ It is not up to me. It's up to "online judge"

Answer (score 0):

It is already solved, but maybe it would help someone in future :D

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,Integer> mapa = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        boolean condition = true;

        for(int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            String imie = sc.next();
            int numer = sc.nextInt();
            mapa.put(imie, numer);
        }

        while(condition == true) {
            try {
                String line;

                while(!(line = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                    lista.add(line);
                }
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException exception) {
                condition=false;
            }
        }

        sc.close();

        for(String k: lista) {
            if(mapa.containsKey(k))
                System.out.println(k + "=" + mapa.get(k));
            else
                System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When does the exception `NoSuchElementException ` occur?

Comment: I tested your code, it does not work for me. Did you test it with the test data given in the web side you referred to it?

Comment: Yes it passed all test- It's same code that I pasted on this side. I have no idea why it is not working for you :/